# How to get the average absolute frequency per hour for each group?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df =
    Id         Datetime
    1          2017-03-02 18:06:20
    1          2017-03-02 18:05:10
    1          2017-04-01 18:04:09
    1          2017-03-02 19:06:50
    1          2017-04-01 19:07:22
    2          2017-03-03 18:09:15
    2          2017-05-03 19:07:05
    2          2017-05-03 20:19:08
```

I want to know the average absolute frequency per hour for each `ID`. In other words, I need to calculate the absolute frequency of `ID` per hours, averaged over days and months. The expected result is this one:

```
ID   HOUR   FREQ
1    18     1.5
1    19     1
1    20     0
2    18     1
2    19     1
2    20     1
```

For example, in case of `ID` equal to 1, there are 2 entries at 18 for the dates `2017-03-02`, and 1 entry at 18 for the date `2017-04-01`. Therefore `FREQ` is equal to `1.5` for `HOUR`=18 and `ID`=1.

I have this code, but `result` does not get created properly:

```
df["Hour"] = df["Datetimr"].apply(lambda x: x.hour)
result = df.groupby(["Id","Hour"]).agg({'Hour':'size'}).reset_index()
```

Comment: there is three instances of `18` according to your code, also your question makes no sense, how are you getting `1.5`

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy:  For `ID` equal to 1, there are 2 instances of 18 on 2017-03-02 and 1 instance on 2017-04-01. So, the average of 2 and 1 is 1.5, isn't it?

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy: Imagine that today there are 10 visitors between 18:00 and 19:00, while yesterday there were 5 visitors in the same timeframe. So, what is the average number of visitors over these two days? `(10 + 5)/2 = 15 / 2 = 7.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#if necessary convert to datetime
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])

#groupby by column, by hours and by dates
df = df.groupby([df['ID'],  df['Datetime'].dt.hour,  df['Datetime'].dt.date]).size()
#groupby by ID and hours
df1 = df.groupby(level=[0,1]).mean()
#add missing values by reindex by Multiindex
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.index.levels[0], df1.index.levels[1]], 
                                 names=df1.index.names)
df1 = df1.reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index(name='FREQ')
print (df1)
   ID  Datetime  FREQ
0   1        18   1.5
1   1        19   1.0
2   1        20   0.0
3   2        18   1.0
4   2        19   1.0
5   2        20   1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this .

```
df["Hour"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime).dt.hour
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime).dt.date
df1=df.groupby(["Id","Hour","Date"]).size().reset_index()
df2=df1.groupby(["Id","Hour"])[0].mean().unstack('Hour').stack('Hour', dropna=False).reset_index()
df2.fillna(0)


Out[265]: 
   Id  Hour    0
0   1    18  1.5
1   1    19  1.0
2   1    20  0.0
3   2    18  1.0
4   2    19  1.0
5   2    20  1.0
```

Comment: In my dataframe `Datetime` has the type `datetime64[ns]`. If I do `df["Datetime"].apply(lambda x: x.date)` and then print values, I see something like `<built-in method date of Timestamp object at 0...`. Also the results that I get seem tobe incorrect. Probably because of `Date`.

Comment: I am using your example data, if you can provide more we can try to help you out .

Comment: Or you can use this one ..`df.Datetime.astype(str).str[0:10]` to get the `Date`

Answer (score 0):

```
df["Hour"] = df["Datetime"].apply(lambda x:x.hour)
df["month"] = df["Datetime"].apply(lambda x:x.month)
dfg = df.groupby(["Id","Hour"])
freq = dfg.size()/dfg["month"].unique().apply(lambda x:len(x))
result = freq.reset_index(name="FREQ")
```

Comment: The counts should be averaged over days. I don't need to estimate a total count for 18 over all days. I want to know the average counts per hours over days. Imagine that today there are 10 visitors between 18:00 and 19:00, while yesterdays there were 5 visitors in the same timeframe. So, what is the average number of visitors over these two days? `(10 + 5)/2 = 15 / 2 = 7.5`

Comment: I understand why FREQ for (1, 18) is 1.5. But why (1, 19) get 2 ?

Comment: You are totally right in this. (1,19) is 1. Sorry about this. Hope all doubts are clarified now.

Comment: still missing one line ...`1    20     0`

Comment: Aha. See the second answer. He gets it.

Comment: @Huang you mean my answer ?

Comment: @Wen , yes! Your answer is better.